# Android GridLayout orientation acting like vertical

Tags: android

I did dive into Android designing not so long ago and can't really understand, why my GridLayout orientation acting like a vertical one, as I clearly stating it as horizontal.(clicking next brings me to EditField below selected, instead of right one). Can someone explain what I'm missing here?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="tiskevicius.armandas.myapplication.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:background="@drawable/ss"
    style="@style/AppTheme"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnCount="7"
        android:rowCount="8"
        android:background="#AA181818"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="3"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:editable="false"
            android:backgroundTint="#21a9e8"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:drawableTint="#aa1e1e"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foregroundTint="#e50e0e"
            android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="0,0"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#21a9e8"
            android:textColorHighlight="#e142c4"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />

        <EditText
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="3"
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:editable="false"
            android:backgroundTint="#21a9e8"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:drawableTint="#aa1e1e"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foregroundTint="#e50e0e"
            android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="0,1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#21a9e8"
            android:textColorHighlight="#e142c4"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />

        <EditText
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="3"
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:backgroundTint="#21a9e8"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:drawableTint="#aa1e1e"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foregroundTint="#e50e0e"
            android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="1,1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#21a9e8"
            android:textColorHighlight="#e142c4"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="3"
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:editable="false"
            android:backgroundTint="#21a9e8"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:drawableTint="#aa1e1e"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foregroundTint="#e50e0e"
            android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="1,2"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#21a9e8"
            android:textColorHighlight="#e142c4"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="3"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:editable="false"
            android:backgroundTint="#21a9e8"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:drawableTint="#aa1e1e"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foregroundTint="#e50e0e"
            android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="1,0"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#21a9e8"
            android:textColorHighlight="#e142c4"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />

        <EditText
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="3"
            android:id="@+id/editText8"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:editable="false"
            android:backgroundTint="#21a9e8"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:drawableTint="#aa1e1e"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foregroundTint="#e50e0e"
            android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="0,2"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#21a9e8"
            android:textColorHighlight="#e142c4"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />

        <EditText
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="3"
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:editable="false"
            android:backgroundTint="#21a9e8"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:drawableTint="#aa1e1e"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foregroundTint="#e50e0e"
            android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="0,3"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#21a9e8"
            android:textColorHighlight="#e142c4"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="3"
            android:id="@+id/editText7"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:editable="false"
            android:backgroundTint="#21a9e8"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:drawableTint="#aa1e1e"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foregroundTint="#21a9e8"
            android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="2,0"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#21a9e8"
            android:textColorHighlight="#e142c4"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="3"
            android:id="@+id/editText9"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:editable="false"
            android:backgroundTint="#21a9e8"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:drawableTint="#aa1e1e"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foregroundTint="#e50e0e"
            android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="2,1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#21a9e8"
            android:textColorHighlight="#e142c4"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />

        <EditText
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="3"
            android:id="@+id/editText10"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:editable="false"
            android:backgroundTint="#21a9e8"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:drawableTint="#aa1e1e"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foregroundTint="#e50e0e"
            android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="2,3"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#21a9e8"
            android:textColorHighlight="#e142c4"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />

    </GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Probably because the items inside your GridLayout cannot fit into the device screen horizontally, so they align 1 by 1 vertically.

Comment: I don't think that's the case, because I can see there are 3 items in the row, i named them 0.0 0.1 0.2 accordingly,  however it is skipping these 2 items and goes to 1.0 item, which is in the next row.